# Relation between Tensor-hom adjunction and adjugate matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism, let $M,N$ be $S$-modules and $Q$ an $R$-module. Then, we have 
>   $$\textrm{Hom}_R(M\otimes_S N,Q) \cong \textrm{Hom}_S(M,\textrm{Hom}_R(N,Q)).$$
>   I want to know whether there is a relation between Tensor-hom adjunction and adjugate  matrix?

Comment: There is a context in which both the situations are instances of a common phenomenon (adjoint pair of functors between enriched categories). Other than that, I doubt there is some stronger relation than some kind of analogy.

Comment: In fact, I think yes, though I suspect it would not be in a computationally/formulaically transparent way. This "Cartan-Eilenberg adjunction" is everywhere, yes! :)